# Android - comparing string to arrays

Tags: android, arrays, string, porter-stemmer

Is it possible to compare strings to arrays in android? This is for the dictionary application using the Porter Stemmer that i am developing for my thesis.

For example the input word is PROCESSES (placed inside a char array), and I'd like to scan if the input contains "s","es" or "sses" then delete them.

I thought of comparing letter by letter but it would be a tedious coding I believe.
Is there an easier way to just compare the input word like so:

```
If ( inputWord has string "es" )
 {
   delete "es
 }

example input: PROCESSES
example output: PROCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(inputWord.contains(checkWord))
{
    int i = inputWord.indexOf(checkWord);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputWord);
    sb = sb.delete(i, i+(checkWord.length()));
    inputWord = sb.toString();
}
```

Store your values in String. It will be more easier. Hope this code will help you. If you have to check multiple words, store all words in a array, and put this snippet inside a for loop.

Comment: i tried using endsWith since what im exactly looking for is the suffixes. changing inputWord.contains(checkWord) to inputWord.endsWith(checkWord) shouldnt be a problem right?

  EDIT: I managed to make your code work now! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how instead of delete is just replace the suffix? I used inputWord.endsWith(checkWord) instead of contains().   What I wanna happen is if the inputWord has this checkWord as suffix, then replace checkWord with another string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.contains and String.replaceAll functionality:

```
//if (inputWord.contains("es")) {
    inputWord.replaceAll("es", "");
//}
```

You don't need the if statement, you can also do directly a replace. If the string is not found it won't do anything.

Comment: Hello, is there a way where I can just replace the suffix? not really ALL occurence of "es". ? I was able to make the code work but what it did is replace all "es" to "".

I used endsWith instead of contains.

Comment: Too bad, there is no replaceLast (Only replaceFirst). What you should do is check with endsWith and create a new string be copying from pos 1 to the start of your occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but you can convert between [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and `char[]` using

```
char[] data = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(data);
```

and

```
String str = "abc";
char[] data = toCharArray();
```

You can check whether a substring is contained using [indexOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [contains(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).